# Centering tikzpicture of a few centimetres

Tags: tikz-pic, center

Good afternoon. I have to center this scheme.
[image]

It's just a matter of a few centimetres :)

The code of that part is the following:

```
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [thick,-]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\centering

\node (mario) [startstop] {Mario};
\node (sara) [startstop, xshift=10cm] {Sara};
\node (convert_m) [process, below of=sara] {Converte $m=78392$};
\node (gen_p_g_a) [process, below of=mario] {Genera $p=104743$, $g=6$ e $a=31152$};
\node (gen_k) [process, below of=convert_m] {Genera $k=4189$};
\node (calcA) [process, below of=gen_p_g_a] {Calcola $A\equiv_p38041$};
\node (invia_A_g) [process, below of=calcA, xshift=5cm] {Invia $A$ e $g$};
\node (riceve_A_g) [process, below of=gen_k] {Riceve $A$ e $g$};
\node (calc_c1_c2) [process, below of=riceve_A_g, text width=3cm] {Calcola $c_1\equiv_p 20758$ \\ e $c_2\equiv_p 18244$};
\node (invia_c1_c2) [process, below of= invia_A_g] {Invia $(c_1,c_2)$};
\node (calc_x) [process, below of=calcA, yshift=-2cm] {Calcola $x^{-1}\equiv_p 56798$};
\node (ottiene_m) [process, below of=calc_x] {Ottiene $m\equiv_p x^{-1}c_2\equiv_p 78392$};


\draw [arrow] (sara) -- (convert_m);
\draw [arrow] (convert_m) -- (gen_k);
\draw [arrow] (gen_k) -- (riceve_A_g);
\draw [arrow] (mario) -- (gen_p_g_a);
\draw [arrow] (gen_p_g_a) -- (calcA);
\draw [arrow] (calcA) -- +(0,-2) -- (invia_A_g);
\draw [arrow] (invia_A_g) -- (riceve_A_g);
\draw [arrow] (riceve_A_g) -- (calc_c1_c2);
\draw [arrow] (calc_c1_c2) -- (invia_c1_c2);
\draw [arrow] (invia_c1_c2) -- (calc_x);
\draw [arrow] (calc_x) -- (ottiene_m);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You need to reduce horizontal distances  between nodes. To show corrected images you need to extend your document to complete small document. Xpo not provide any information about your page layout

Comment: @Dan Please note that `\tikzstyle` is obsolete

Comment: Any news? Does any of received answer solves your problem? If yes, accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of selected answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would redraw your picture ...

- redefine picture elements styles (all "process" node have equal width)
- nodes and arrows styles are inserts as `tikzpicture` options
- for node positioning use of `positioning` library syntax
- determine and use only common horizontal and vertical distances between nodes
- drawing of picture would start at "Sara" node

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=6mm and 8mm,
 start chain = going below,
%
base/.style = {draw, text width = 40mm, align=center},
startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners, text width = 20mm},
  process/.style = {base},
      arr/.style = {-Stealth, thick},
every join/.style = {arr}
                   ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={base,on chain, join}]
\node (sara)        [startstop] {Sara};  
\node (convert_m)   [process]   {Converte $m=78392$};
\node (gen_k)       [process]   {Genera\\ $k=4189$};
\node (riceve_A_g)  [process]   {Riceve $A$ e $g$};
\node (calc_c1_c2)  [process]   {Calcola\\ $c_1\equiv_p 20758$ \\ e $c_2\equiv_p 18244$};
    \end{scope}
\node (invia_A_g)   [process,
                     left=of riceve_A_g]    {Invia $A$ e $g$};
\node (invia_c1_c2) [process,
                     left = of calc_c1_c2]  {Invia $(c_1,c_2)$};
    \begin{scope}[nodes={base,on chain, join}]
\node (mario)       [startstop,
                     suspend join,
                     left= 80mm of sara] {Mario};   % 50mm = 11mm+8mm+42mm+8mm+11mm
\node (gen_p_g_a)   [process]   {Genera $p=104743$, $g=6$ e $a=31152$};
\node (calcA)       [process]   {Calcola $A\equiv_p38041$};
    \end{scope}
\node (calc_x)      [process,
                     left=of invia_c1_c2]        {Calcola $x^{-1}\equiv_p 56798$};
\node (ottiene_m)   [process, below=of calc_x]  {Ottiene $m\equiv_p x^{-1}c_2\equiv_p 78392$};
% arrows out of join macro
\draw[arr]  (calcA) |- (invia_A_g);
\draw[arr]  (invia_A_g) -- (riceve_A_g);
\draw[arr]  (calc_c1_c2) -- (invia_c1_c2);
\draw[arr]  (invia_c1_c2) -- (calc_x);
\draw[arr]   (calc_x)     -- (ottiene_m);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could have proposed a minimal compilable code, here we don't even know which class you are using.
Otherwise to answer, the changepage package allows to locally modify the margins with the environment \begin{adjustwidth}{...}{...}.
As here you have to center a float in the page, you have to put this environment in the float.

Note: I made the choice not to modify the image to make it more compact but to answer a more general question of centering an image larger than the text box

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [thick,-]


%\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (mario) [startstop] {Mario};
\node (sara) [startstop, xshift=10cm] {Sara};
\node (convert_m) [process, below of=sara] {Converte $m=78392$};
\node (gen_p_g_a) [process, below of=mario] {Genera $p=104743$, $g=6$ e $a=31152$};
\node (gen_k) [process, below of=convert_m] {Genera $k=4189$};
\node (calcA) [process, below of=gen_p_g_a] {Calcola $A\equiv_p38041$};
\node (invia_A_g) [process, below of=calcA, xshift=5cm] {Invia $A$ e $g$};
\node (riceve_A_g) [process, below of=gen_k] {Riceve $A$ e $g$};
\node (calc_c1_c2) [process, below of=riceve_A_g, text width=3cm] {Calcola $c_1\equiv_p 20758$ \\ e $c_2\equiv_p 18244$};
\node (invia_c1_c2) [process, below of= invia_A_g] {Invia $(c_1,c_2)$};
\node (calc_x) [process, below of=calcA, yshift=-2cm] {Calcola $x^{-1}\equiv_p 56798$};
\node (ottiene_m) [process, below of=calc_x] {Ottiene $m\equiv_p x^{-1}c_2\equiv_p 78392$};


\draw [arrow] (sara) -- (convert_m);
\draw [arrow] (convert_m) -- (gen_k);
\draw [arrow] (gen_k) -- (riceve_A_g);
\draw [arrow] (mario) -- (gen_p_g_a);
\draw [arrow] (gen_p_g_a) -- (calcA);
\draw [arrow] (calcA) -- +(0,-2) -- (invia_A_g);
\draw [arrow] (invia_A_g) -- (riceve_A_g);
\draw [arrow] (riceve_A_g) -- (calc_c1_c2);
\draw [arrow] (calc_c1_c2) -- (invia_c1_c2);
\draw [arrow] (invia_c1_c2) -- (calc_x);
\draw [arrow] (calc_x) -- (ottiene_m);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{bla bla}
\label{fig:}

\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}


\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]